# Adding custom images from firebase storage into email templates in firebase authentication

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, firebase-storage

I am trying to customize the password reset email template to include a personalized image from firebase storage. Is there any way to do so within the firebase authentication template message or is the only way to host my own action handler page and adding to the the action URL?